# How to specify a path in a properties file to be loaded with Java Properties

Tags: java, properties, path

I have a .properties file I want to load in a Java Properties object.
The file contains some paths. In order to be able to load the properties file without getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.` when loading the properties from the file with the method Properties.load(), I need to use the escape character '\' in the path.

So my path looks like: `C:\\Users\\Harald\\Folder1\\Version1\\Folder2`. And it works this way, no exception is thrown.

The problem is that I can't explain to my user (because this path can be changed by the user!) that he needs to use double '\' in the path.

Does anybody knows a work-around for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the ability to intercept the file name before being sent to the `load()` method?

Comment: Do you read the properties and then load properties from there?

Comment: @adarshr: No, I can't intercept it.

Comment: You question doesn't make much sense, could you post some relevant code and sample input? I don't think I follow you. How does you properties look like? How does the code that uses that properties look like?

Comment: @OscarRyz The code that uses the properties is the `java.util.Properties` class which requires that you escape backslashes.  OP does not want the user to deal with this.

Comment: @krock: Thanks. I think It may be as simple as `properties.load(new StringReader( previouslyProcessedWithEscapedBackSlashAndOtherFileContentHere ) );`  but is hard to tell since the OP doesn't provide more info.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even simpler solution is to **use forward slashes**. This way your path will look like `C:/Users/Harald/Folder1/Version1/Folder2` and everything else will just work - no code change required!

Comment: that is called a forward slash

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused with your question. Are you asking if there is a way that you can have a user edit the properties file without having to use non-intuitive \ escape character?

If you are setting this up for a user to be able to edit perhaps you should have a program or script to create the properties file (adding in escape characters when needed)

Comment: Yes, you understood exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: Then you probably want to have a small interface for the user to put in paths. A small dialog a user can use to select the path he wants. May even help to have a file browser so instead of manually typing a path the user can browse to the path. Then just simply add in the \'s where appropriate.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion - I just parse the .properties file and take the path as it is there (presumably the user wrote it correctly). So I don't use Java's Properties in this way.

Comment: I am saying add a layer between the user and the creation of the .properties file to generate the .properties file in the way java needs to parse it. Also can make the program more user friendly and would be the appropriate UI thing to do if this is a program used by a typical computer user (i.e. not another programmer).

Comment: Yeah, but in my case it doesn't worth the effort of adding a new layer. The user just the paths there once and that's it. It's simpler just to parse the properties file and put the paths in a ArrayList<String>. But thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off defining a path for the user to place a properties file, or point them to an existing properties file (that contains comments about useful properties etc.) e.g. `${user.home}\\myapp\\myprops.properties` and then always load that file, or better yet, just provide the directory and load every file that ends in `.properties` in that directory.

If your application is a GUI app, you could also allow the user to select a file in a file dialog box.  The strings you get back out of swing and SWT labels and file choosers are java friendly and you needn't worry about escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

if in java code use `\\`

if in the properties file use `/`